# Is this a better way that I could optimize my flowchart?

Tags: algorithm, flowchart

I am trying to create a flowchart for my raspberry pi + arduino thesis project. My system is a vending machine that lets you buy or dispose a facemask. But of course, it has to have a sensor which would detect the facemask slot, disinfectant level, and disposal bin fill levels.

This is what is supposed to be:
If the disinfectant container is empty or facemask slot is empty and disposal bin is at critical (full) level, it automatically send SMS to person in charge once every 15 minutes and will not provide any services. If the facemask slot is not empty and disposal bin is at critical (full) level, display only "Buy facemask" and will also send SMS to notify that disposal in is at critical level. But if the facemask slot is empty and disposal bin is not in critical level, display only "Dispose facemask" and will send SMS too. If everything is fine, display both services in the menu.

Please let me know what should I do to improve my flowchart. Thanks.

[image: vending machine]